# hadoop permissions issue (hdfs-site.xml dfs.permissions.enabled)

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hive, hdfs, cloudera

I recently installed Hadoop on my machine. And i'm having permissions issue. I logged in as user rahul and tried to create an directory in HDFS(`hdfs dfs -mkdir /rahul_workspace`). But it gave me an error `Permission denied: user=Rahul, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x`. A quick Google search for this error lead to many responses suggesting the workaround of disabling permission checking by setting the `dfs.permissions` property in `hdfs-site.xml` to `false`. 
Now i can crate the directories in HDFS. With the above property set to false can i access all the other hadoop services such as hive, pig, sqoop etc.,?

Answer (score 2):

dfs.permissions is the property which can be used to enable/disable HDFS ACL (simple permission). With dfs.permission set to false any user can create/delete  files/directories anywhere in HDFS.

With this property set to false, You can access all other Hadoop services such as Hive, Pig etc.

Answer (score 2):

HDFS treats the user who started the namenode process as the 'superuser'.  This user is typically the `hdfs` user.  The `/user` directory you are trying to write to is owned by `hdfs` user and `hdfs` group with read and execute permissions to any user in `hdfs` group and others.

Disabling permissions seems a little extreme.  You have a few options here, the first is to create your user directory as the `hdfs` user.

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs fs -mkdir /rahul_workspace
sudo -u hdfs hdfs fs -chown Rahul /rahul_workspace
```

This will create your directory and change the ownership to you.  Another option is to create your directory in an area where you already have write permissions.  Typically /tmp is wide open.

```
hdfs fs -mkdir /tmp/rahul_workspace
```

Answer (score 1):

On Cloudera:
What I do, created one user with default permissions on Hue i.e. user1

Then, from linux shell, First do access hdfs user permissions :
`export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs`

Then for your linux user name like "user1":

try:
`hdfs dfs -chown user1:user1 /`

Now if you got the proper permissions:

try to create directory on '/': 
`hdfs dfs -mkdir /testuser1`

Answer (score 0):

We have used

hadoop fs -setfacl -m -R user:xyz:rwx /data/dev/dl/fvc/df

to overcome this problem on top level directory(/data).